# PHP Automated reply message needs to pause before adding reply to MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, automated-tests, message

I am using a really really simple method here using basic PHP to get started on an automated reply system using my already working messaging feature. I know that I am not using the best methods of security here but that's not what this is about so please avoid commenting on the security of the script.

Now, when the user sends a reply from a form named `reply` it decides if the user is talking to the automated reply feature, with a `user_id` of `0`. It it is, `$sarssystem` returns as `1`. If it doesn't return as `1` the form will process as a general message, which works perfectly. Here is the form process:

```
///////////// ADD REPLY TO CONVERSATION //////////////////////////////
if(isset($_POST['reply'])){
    $user_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $conversation_id = $_POST['conversation_id'];
    $sarssystem = $_POST['sarssystem'];

    if(isset($sarssystem)){
    if($sarssystem == 1){
        include 'system/sars_system.php';
    } else {

        $reply = str_replace("'","\\'",$message); 


mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ap_messages (message_id, message, sender_id, time_sent, time_read, conversation_id) 
VALUES ('','$reply','$user_id', NOW(), '', '$conversation_id')");   

    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ap_conversations SET time = NOW() WHERE conversation_id = '$conversation_id'");

    }
    } else {

        $reply = str_replace("'","\\'",$message); 


mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ap_messages (message_id, message, sender_id, time_sent, time_read, conversation_id) 
VALUES ('','$reply','$user_id', NOW(), '', '$conversation_id')");   

    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ap_conversations SET time = NOW() WHERE conversation_id = '$conversation_id'");

    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

If it returns as `1` and you ARE replying to the automated service, it will `include` a file to add your message AND a automatic reply in to the database:

system/sars_system.php:

```
if($message == 'hello'){
    $sarsreply = 'hey, how are you?';
}

$usr_message = str_replace("'","\\'",$message);

mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ap_messages (message_id, message, sender_id, time_sent, time_read, conversation_id) 
VALUES ('','$usr_message','$user_id', NOW(), NOW(), '$conversation_id')");

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ap_conversations SET time = NOW() WHERE conversation_id = '$conversation_id'");

sleep(3);

mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ap_messages (message_id, message, sender_id, time_sent, time_read, conversation_id) 
VALUES ('','$sarsreply','0', NOW(), '', '$conversation_id')");
```

As you can see it is MAJORLY basic, and only a test to get it working, I can do more work once this is working as it should be and the problem I am getting is trying to add the users reply and displaying it normally, then waiting for a couple seconds before adding the AUTOMATED reply. I tried to use the `sleep()` function as you can see but that just delays the entire page when I hit send to add my reply, the entire page seems to freeze for 3 seconds and then both user and automated replies fly on the screen at the same time. I am trying to add the user reply first, then wait a few seconds and then add the automated reply to the database. Is there another function rather than `sleep()` I can use to get these results?

AS REQUESTED - Code to retrieve messages and display conversation:

```
$conversation_id = $convoid;   
$res4=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ap_conversations WHERE conversation_id = '$conversation_id'");
while($row4=mysqli_fetch_array($res4))
{   
 $co_conversation_id = $row4['conversation_id'];
 $co_user_one = $row4['user_one'];
 $co_user_two = $row4['user_two'];
 if($co_user_one == $user_id){
    $co_recip = $co_user_two; 
 } else if($co_user_two == $user_id){
    $co_recip = $co_user_one; 
 }
 if($co_recip == '0'){
    $sarssystem = 1;
 } else {
     $sarssystem = 0;
 }
$res5=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ap_messages WHERE conversation_id = '$conversation_id'");
while($row5=mysqli_fetch_array($res5))
{   
 $co_message_id = $row5['message_id'];
 $co_message = $row5['message'];
 $co_sender_id = $row5['sender_id'];
 $co_time_read = $row5['time_read'];

}
$res6=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ap_users WHERE user_id = '$co_recip'");
while($row6=mysqli_fetch_array($res6))
{   
 $co_first_name = $row6['first_name'];
 $co_last_name = $row6['last_name'];
}



?>  
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div style="display:inline"><? echo ''.$co_first_name.' '.$co_last_name.''; ?></div> <div align="right" style="display:inline; float:right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="location.href='messages.php';"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> New</button></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
<?
}
?>                            
 <div class="list-group-message" style="overflow-y: scroll;height:385px;width:680px">                           
<?
$res6=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ap_messages WHERE conversation_id = '$conversation_id' ORDER BY time_sent ASC");
while($row6=mysqli_fetch_array($res6))
{   
 $me_message = $row6['message'];
 $me_message_id = $row6['message_id'];
 $me_sender_id = $row6['sender_id'];
 $todaysdate = date('d/m/Y');
 $me_time_sent_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row6['time_sent']));
 $me_time_sent_date_and_time = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($row6['time_sent']));
 $me_time_sent_time = date('H:i', strtotime($row6['time_sent']));
 if($todaysdate == $me_time_sent_date){
     $me_time = ''.$me_time_sent_time.'';
 } else {
    $me_time = ''.$me_time_sent_date.' '.$me_time_sent_time.''; 
 }


 $me_time_read = $row6['time_read'];
$res7=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ap_users WHERE user_id = '$me_sender_id'");
while($row7=mysqli_fetch_array($res7))
{   
 $me_first_name = $row7['first_name'];
 $me_last_name = $row7['last_name'];
  $me_display_img = $row7['display_img'];
}

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ap_messages SET time_read = NOW() WHERE message_id = '{$me_message_id}' AND time_read = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND conversation_id = '$co_conversation_id' AND sender_id != '$user_id'");
?>  




<div class="media" style="max-width: <? echo $screenwidth; ?>px;">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="userimg/<? echo $me_display_img; ?>" alt="user" width="64px" height="64px" hspace="10px" class="media-object" align="left">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body" style="position: relative !important;">
    <div style="display:inline"><b><a href=""><? echo ''.$me_first_name.' '.$me_last_name.''; ?></a></b></div> <div align="right" style="float:right; display:inline"> <? echo $me_time; ?> </div><br>
    <? echo $me_message; ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?
}
?>
```

Comment: May I ask, why is there any requirement of a pause?

Comment: For a couple reasons, without a pause sometimes the auto reply jumps ahead of the users message, it happens a bit too quick and looks silly and I think it would confuse the users of the site.

Comment: Can we see the code you're using to pull records from the database into the conversation? My initial reaction is to modify the timestamp of the record you're automatically creating to +5 seconds `DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL 5 SECOND)`, and filter your records on the other side based on time_sent `<= NOW()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments, I would increase the timestamp using `DATE_ADD()`:

```
if($message == 'hello'){
    $sarsreply = 'hey, how are you?';
}

$usr_message = str_replace("'","\\'",$message);

mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ap_messages (message_id, message, sender_id, time_sent, time_read, conversation_id) 
VALUES ('','$usr_message','$user_id', NOW(), NOW(), '$conversation_id')");

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ap_conversations SET time = NOW() WHERE conversation_id = '$conversation_id'");

mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ap_messages (message_id, message, sender_id, time_sent, time_read, conversation_id) 
VALUES ('','$sarsreply','0', DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL 5 SECOND), '', '$conversation_id')");
```

Comment: I've edited my question to include the code you asked for, would this answer still be the suggested route forward?

Comment: @Snappysites I would attempt it and see if it behaves as you expect. Are you pulling in conversation messages on page reload, or via some AJAX/JavaScript call, or...?

Comment: I've tested it and it does solve the problem of the automated message jumping above the users message although its still very fast. At the moment I am using just the page reload but I hope to upgrade it to work with Ajax as you have to reload the page to view any normal users replies - always frustrating!